# apostrophe or not?

Tags: grammar

I'm writing a cover letter and I need to know if I should say: I would like to be part of the Publix family vs Publix's family.

Please help!!

Comment: Publix family .

Answer (score 0):

No 's.

The name of the corporation covers all members. In other words, it's not the Publix corporation and it's family.

It's easier to see if you try it with companies that have a name that doesn't end in the 's' sound. 'I would like to be a part of the Walmart family', 'I would like to be a part of the Chrysler family'. Same deal for an actual family if you were marrying into it or being adopted.

Answer (score 0):

Without apostrophe. An apostrophe would make them two separate entities which they are not.